# update camera_info in ueye_cam

Tags: ros, ueye-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the ROS package ueye_cam (fuerte branch) and I would like to know how update the camera_info.

I do the calibration with camera_calibration ROS package, I convert the calibration info in .yaml file and I put these files in /home/../.ros/camera_info.

If I run

roslaunch ueye_cam master_slaves_rgb8.launch  and I do rostopic echo /master/camera_info, I don't see the new value.

How can I update these values?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125666/update-camera_info-in-ueye_cam/) by [Vero](https://answers.ros.org/users/10711/vero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is a bug in ueye_cam's calibration parser, where it loads a yaml file, but parses the format of a Videre INI file instead. This will be fixed very soon. For the time being, you can manually modify the contents of your .yaml file according to the [Videre INI specs](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration_parsers#File_formats) (yuk, I know, sorry).

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2014-10-16**:
Fixed: https://github.com/anqixu/ueye_cam/commit/467abc5d17fc101accd076cc52009ef9a2db7522